# Write SQL query to Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-6

```
select * 
from [InterViewerComment]   
where commentID in (select max(commentID) as commentID 
                    from [InterViewerComment] 
                    where jobID = 45 
                    group by qenID)
```

This query is correct in SQL, but I want to rewrite it in Entity Framework.
Basically, I want the latest comment for each qenID based on job ID.

Comment: What have you done so far? Linq?

Comment: No idea how to do nested level queries in Entity framework finally i used some other way

Answer (score 0):

Other way to do the same

var query = " select qendidateList.qenName,InterViewerComment.*, candidate_status.status, 0 as ExamMarks, 0 as Skills  from [InterViewerComment] " +
                           " left outer join qendidateList on InterViewerComment.qenID = qendidateList.qenID  " +
                           " left outer join candidate_status on InterViewerComment.candidate_status = candidate_status.Candidate_status  " +
                           "  where commentID in( select max(commentID) as commentID from[InterViewerComment] where jobID = 45 group by qenID)";

```
        var CandidateComm_ = db.Database.SqlQuery<interViewerComment>(query).ToList();
```